# How are Virtualenv site-packages created?

Tags: virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv, site-packages

I am using pipenv on Mac and see some site-packages installed in the ~/virtualenv/python3.9/. In my case there is an OpenSSL and I'm not sure how it got there seeing as there is no corresponding entry in pipfile. I take this to mean it is duplicated from the system or it was added with pipenv then remove from pipfile?

Comment: Something has requested it as a dependency, not necessary as a direct dependency. Is it in `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: @phd negative on the lock file. What something would you imagine? Trying to figure out how to update OpenSSL because https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/7959

Comment: `pip` cannot list reverse dependencies so you need a tool like [pipdeptree](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pipdeptree).